# If $f:\mathbb{R} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ satisfies $f'(a) \neq 0$ for all $a \in \mathbb{R}$, show that $f$ is one-to-one.

Tags: real-analysis

If $f:\mathbb{R} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ satisfies $f'(a) \neq 0$ for all $a \in \mathbb{R}$, show that $f$ is one-to-one for all $a\in \mathbb{R}$.

### My attempt

We know that $f(a)$ is not a constant because $f'(a)\neq 0$.Define $f$ by $f(a)=bx$. $f'(a)=x\neq 0$

If $f(x)=f(v)$ then $$bx=bv$$

$$x=v$$

Thus, $f$ is one-to-one.

Comment: This is hard to follow.    Hint:  use the Mean Value Theorem.

Comment: Hmm.. if I tried with the mean value theorem I would say... Let $f$ be continuous and differentiable at $(a,b)$ then there exists $c$ such that $f'(c)=\frac{f(a)-f(b)}{a-b}$. Not sure where to go from there though...

Comment: It looks like you're assuming every non-constant function is of the form $f(x) = bx$ for some $b$ which is pretty wrong, unless I'm misunderstanding you're attempt.

Comment: Assume for a contradiction that $f$ is not one-to-one, then there exist distinct $a,b$ such that $f(a) = f(b)$. Now try using MVT.

Comment: So, suppose that you have $a<b$ but $f(a)=f(b)$.  Now what does the MVT tell you?

Comment: @lulu then $f'(c)=0$

Comment: Isn't this simply the contrapositive of Rolle's theorem?

Comment: Right, $f'(c)$ would equal $0$.  But is that possible under your assumption about $f'$?

Answer (score 2):

A function which is the derivative of another function has the inttermediate value property. therefore, if $f'(a)\ne 0$ for all $a\in\mathbf R$, $f'$ has a constant sign, and  $f$ is increasing or decreasing on $\mathbf R$. In any case, it is one-to-one.

Answer (score 2):

"$f(a)$ is not a constant" means what? If $a$ is a number, then $f(a)$ is a number.  You mean $f$ is not constant.  And you can't say $f(a)=bx$, and it isn't clear what that means; what are $b$ and $x$?  And this wouldn't imply $f'(a) = x$.

If you are going to prove that the hypothesis implies the conclusion, you can't assume what form the function has. The above is hard to follow, but it is more along the lines of showing that an example exists that satisfies the hypothesis and the conclusion, rather than proving anything.

---

In a proof by contraposition, we can show that if $f:\mathbb R\to\mathbb R$ is a differentiable function that is not one-to-one, then there exists $a\in\mathbb R$ such that $f'(a)=0$.

So suppose that $f$ is differentiable and not one-to-one.  Then there exist $x_1$ and $x_2$ not equal such that $f(x_1)=f(x_2)$.  By the Mean Value Theorem, or the special case called Rolle's Theorem, there is a number $a$ between $x_1$ and $x_2$ such that $f'(a) = 0$.

Answer (score 0):

The intermediate value property of a derivative is not needed to get our conclusion. Simply apply the Mean Value Theorem: if $x\ne y$ then there exists an intermmediate point $a$ between $x$ and $y$ s.t. $f(y)-f(x)=f'(a)(y-x)\ne 0$ which means that $f(x)\ne f(y)$.